# Como CONSUMIR un servicio web REST con Spring (Java)?

Tags: java, spring

Buen día.
Mi pregunta es, ¿como puedo consumir un servicio web REST desde mi aplicación que esta hecha con spring framework?.
La documentacion de spring me dice que lo puedo hacer con restTemplate.
Por ejemplo para obtener datos:

```
restTemplate.getForObject(uri,class,200);
```

pero me sale este error

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
```

Comment: Lo estás utilizando correctamente. El problema parece ser que necesitas autenticarte con el sitio primero, el error 403 significa que no estás autenticado y/o no tienes autorización con tus credenciales para acceder a ese recurso.

Comment: Hola Luiggi Mendoza, gracias por tu respuesta. Este es el servicio del cual deseo obtener los datos:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Este servicio es publico, aun asi, ¿debo autenticarme?

Comment: Si el servicio es público entonces no necesitas autenticación. Sería importante que publiques todo el código necesario para reproducir el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Es una protección de seguridad necesitas desactivar CSRF, o verficar que tipo de seguridad o credencia usa el web service  del la apalicación requerida

Answer (score 0):

El error 403 se da en  respuesta a un cliente de una página web o servicio para indicar que el servidor se niega a permitir la acción solicitada.

Lo habitual es que se deba a que el servicio está securizado y no se puede invocar tal cual lo estás haciendo.

RestTemplate da soporte para autenticación básica por ejemplo y podrías hacer algo así:

```
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = 
(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory(); 
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = (DefaultHttpClient) 
requestFactory.getHttpClient();
 httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
 new AuthScope(host, port, AuthScope.ANY_REALM),
 new UsernamePasswordCredentials("name", "pass"));
```

Y luego ya podrías invocar al servicio Rest de la siguiente manera:

`restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/spring-security-rest-template/api/foos/1", HttpMethod.GET, null, Foo.class)`;

Se debe incluir la dependencia de apache httpcomponents además de la spring-mvc.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el API no requiere autenticación el error esta en la implementación. Acá esta el código funcional que obtiene los datos de la URL que que especificas.

```
@Test    
public void test_whenList() {
            RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
            ResponseEntity<List<Response>> exchange = rt.exchange("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
                    HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Response>>() {
                    });
            List<Response> body = exchange.getBody();
            Response response = body.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
            assertThat(response.getUserId(), is(1));

        }

@Test
public void test_whenObject() {
    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<Response> exchange = rt.exchange("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/4", HttpMethod.GET,
            null, Response.class);
    Response response = exchange.getBody();
    assertThat(response.getId(), is(4));

}
```

El objeto de respuesta es acorde a el API:

```
public Response() {
    super();
}

private Integer userId;
private Integer id;
private String title;
private String body;
```